# how to take wifi network in cable & again cable to wifi

Tags: router, network-discovery

I am web developer, only have limited knowledge about networking.

My Problem is, 
I have a wifi notwork on first floor of building and living at 8th floor.(First floor wifi is not mine, but i have wifi login).
And i want to access this first floor wifi at 8th floor.(I can't do anything with other person(First floor) wifi router & cables, only can access wifi.)

I have tried to search about this & find solution like use of wifi repeater on each floor till 8th floor to carry wifi, but it's costly to use so many wifi repeater.

So i am looking like solution, that take this wifi in cable & use cable from first floor to 8th floor & then again cable to wifi. is it possible to catch wifi by some devices & pass by cable..??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sadly, the community voted home / consumer networking off-topic.  Please consider asking on [su]

Comment: @MikePennington hurrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
I were thinking this is networking related question...Sorry if anyone hurt lot from my question here...I got answer now...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to run a cable from the first floor to the eighth floor, then use wife on the eighth floor.

With that in mind, you should run said cable and attach a wireless access point or wireless router at the other end.

Keep in mind that there are cabling standards, building codes, and fire codes that must be met in the terms of distance, as well as running cable in any sort of riser area or plenum.

Comment: thanks for reply,
Yes i want a cable from first floor to 8th floor, i have LAN cable, i think that will work fine?

But i want know which device should i connect both end of cable, at 8th floor end will attach wireless access point but what about first floor cable end? is there any device that can transfer wifi to cable??

Comment: @KuldeepChoudhary if it was me (and could rightfully run the cable), I would do a wireless access point on floor 1, run a cable from an available ethernet port to the 8th floor, and attach another access point to the other end. I have a similar setup at my home: but going from the 1st floor to the 8th floor of a building with a single cable seems like a long way to me.

Comment: A simple access point at each end won't do it. On the first floor you will need a wireless "bridge". Note that some APs can be configured to work as bridges, and that would be ok. On the eighth floor you'll want a regular access point. You will set the bridge to the SSID on the first floor, and the AP to some other SSID that you make up. Note that using an "access point/router" may cause problems if there is already a router on the first floor, as you will then be doing "double NAT". If such problems occur you'll be limited to just one client device on the 8th floor.